# Minimal API Unsupported media type (415) after processing by middleware

Tags: c#, .net, gzip, .net-6.0

I'm using a Gzip middleware, which decompresses `"application/gzip"` requests and changes them to `"application/json"`. It works in .Net 3.1 and 5, but in .Net 6 (Minimal API) I get status 415 (*Unsupported media type*) response. The middleware remained unchanged, in a seperate project (.net standard 2.1). In debugger everything seems to work at first, request is processed by the middleware as always and passed further. I tried sending a normal json with only content-type header changed, and got the same error.

**UPDATE:** I found more middleware code. I need to process the requests with `"content-type": "application/gzip"` because that is the format sent by a lot of legacy devices communicating with the api.

Program.cs:

```
//... Services ...//
#region Middleware
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())

{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
});

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseGzipRequestDecompression(); // My custom middleware
app.UseGlobalExceptionHandler();
#endregion //Middleware
```

Middleware:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        if (request.ContentType == "application/gzip")
        {
            
            using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(request.Body, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                await gzipStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
            }

            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            
            // Replace request content with the newly decompressed stream
            request.Body = outputStream;
            
            // Change request type to json
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: @davidfowl added the program.cs and middleware code, check new edit

Comment: _"I'm using a Gzip middleware, which decompresses "application/gzip" requests and changes them to "application/json""_ - why though? Anyway this middleware you obtained or wrote breaks something, probably. If it's a black box to you, it now definitely is to us.

Comment: gzip should be a content encoding not a content type.

Comment: @CodeCaster the middleware was written quite a few years ago by someone who doesn't work in my company anymore. It was a part of a huge monolithic project that I want to split into microservices. It has to be compatible with previous implementations

Comment: @JeremyLakeman sadly this is not up to me, I have to work with what I recieve

Comment: I suspect that `.UseRouting` has already decided that there is no valid end point. You might need to swap order of the middleware around.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I tried removing the ```.UseRouting``` and sadly the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@JeremyLakeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4139809/jeremy-lakeman), the problem was in `.UseRouting`.

According to [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

> Apps typically don't need to call UseRouting or UseEndpoints. WebApplicationBuilder configures a middleware pipeline that wraps middleware added in Program.cs with UseRouting and UseEndpoints. However, apps can change the order in which UseRouting and UseEndpoints run by calling these methods explicitly.

The solution was to move the .UseRouting after the middleware (and not to delete it), so it looked like this:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseGzipRequestDecompression();
app.UseGlobalExceptionHandler();
app.UseRouting();
#endregion //Middleware
```